# what is the best approach to notify per email the user when an event occurs - django

Tags: python, django, message

So lets say that user x sends a message to user y on a website.
User y is notified on the website, but it doesn't get any email about this.

The only thing that I am thinking of to solve this is to stick some code to send out an email to user y after the code where user x sends the message to user y.

```
def send_msg(request)
    #request.user sends message to other_user
    #send email to other_user and let him know about his new message
```

I dont know how good this approach is, in terms of performance.

What are your thoughts? How would you approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance, you can use [django-mailer](https://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer/). django-mailer provides an email backend that queues emails rather than sending it directly. Emails are then [sent by a cron job](https://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer/blob/master/docs/usage.txt#L42) which you should setup, running `manage.py send_mail`.

Also, you might want to use [django-notification](https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/) app, it has a nice pattern for notification emails + provides a view for the user to check/uncheck the types of notification he/she wants/doesn't want to get by email.

Comment: django-notification looks like it got potential :) will try it out, thanks

Comment: I will do that as soon as I test the app, no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a post_save signal to send the email after the message has been saved to the model would be one solution. Although for performance an email queue solution would be recommended.